# Explicit form of recurrence relation when the recurring term is an exponent

Tags: notation, recurrence-relations

Suppose I have the sequence

$u_0 = 1$
$u_1 = 3$
$u_2 = 27$
$u_n = 3^{u_{n-1}}$, for integer $n > 0$

As you can see, the nth term is 3 raised to the power of $u_{n-1}$th term, which forms a sort of recurrence relation.

Is there a way to find an explicit form for this sequence? How?

Comment: $u_n= 3^{3^{3^{\dots^3}}}$ where $n$ threes appear. There is no simpler form to write this down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, this is written $u_n=\ ^n3$. This operation is called [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).